# Getting IIS logs location - server 2k8 & c#

Tags: iis, logging, azure, windows-server-2008

We have a bunch of servers running on Azure (and IIS 7.5). I trying to write a standalone application that periodically aggregates the log files from the server to a central location. And by aggregation, it would literally be about pointing our custom uploader at the directory and let it do it's thing.

Is there an easy way to (programmatically) get the location of the logdir configured for my site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AaronS' answer is in the good direction, but there are some points I wanted to add:

- If you want to access ServerManager from your WebRole.cs you'll need to run your role in evelated context in order to be allowed use ServerManager.

> ```
> <Runtime executionContext="elevated"/>
> ```

- Like AaronS already explained, you can use ServerManager to access the log directory. This sample code is a little more "Azure-friendly":

---

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    var siteName = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web";
    var id = serverManager.Sites[siteName].Id;
    var logFile = serverManager.Sites[siteName].LogFile;

    var iisLogDirectory = String.Format("{0}\\W3SVC{1}", logFile.Directory, id);
}
```

---

- Why not simply use the Windows Azure Diagnostics? As you can see from the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.diagnosticmonitorconfiguration.aspx), wad-**iis-failedreqlogfiles**, wad-**iis-logfiles**, and wad-**crash-dump** are automatically taken into account. This means if you configure the DiagnosticMonitor properly, it will ship your logs every X minutes to a storage account. This is great if you have multiple servers running (and even if you only have 1), since you can access all your logs in a central place. I've used CloudXplorer recently to access my logs since it gives you an Explorer-like experience when browsing your files.

**Note:** For my 3 remarks I'm assuming you are using a PaaS WebRole (and not a IaaS VM).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. As for using a storage account, we considered it but ultimately decided against it for several customer reasons/goals. That would have made everything a lot simpler though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the IIS7 log file location by using something similar to the following:

```
using (ServerManager manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("yourservername"))
{
     Site defaultSite = manager.Sites[0];
     string loglocation=defaultSite.LogFile.Directory;
}
```

It will return a string in this format: "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"

Comment: FYI: The remote target must be running the IIS 'Management Service'.  The service must be enabled and started; otherwise you will not be able to query this information.  See [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/remote-administration/remote-administration-for-iis-manager) page for more information regarding the installation and configuration of the IIS remote administration service.